# Laravel Form helper not show data after validation error

Tags: forms, laravel, validation, form-helpers

i'm having problem with forms helper in laravel 5.3.
I have a foreach that shows my data in a form.
Everythins work fine, until i submit a form and validation fails.
Therefore, when validation fails, the input text in my form not show the previus data, but only the data which were submitted.
Here the code:

```
@foreach($cars as $car)
    {!! Form::model($car, ['route' => ['cars.update', $car->id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
        <div class="col-md-2">
            {{ Form::label('name', $car->name) }}
            {{ Form::text('name', $car->name, ['class' => 'editbox-normal']) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            {{ Form::label('phone', 'Phone') }}
            {{ Form::text('phone', null, ['class' => 'editbox-normal']) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            {{ Form::label('license_plate', 'License plate') }}
            {{ Form::text('license_plate', null, ['class' => 'editbox-normal']) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            {{ Form::label('total_km', 'KM') }}
            {{ Form::text('total_km', null, ['class' => 'editbox-normal']) }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-3 flex-space-around">
            {{ Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-edit']) }}
        </div>
    {!! Form::close() !!}
@endforeach
```

If i submit one of those forms and validation fails, for example name is required and name input is empty, laravel flash $error, but every input of each form displays the data of the submitted form. In this example, every name input will be empty, and phone, license_plate and total_km will have the same value.
Instead, if i use pure html code for the input, everythinks work fine.
In addition, if you notice, the fist label has the value set to $car->name, the same of the text input, but in the label it is shows correctly, in the input not.
Anyone knows why?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us how you do validation? Is it in controller or do you have it in Request or maybe some other form?

Comment: I'm using Request validation.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually intended behaviour. This way, when you e.g. forget to enter your name, the rest of the data you entered isn't lost.
In your use case, however, this leads to unintended results (because you have multiple forms on the same page). I would advise splitting the forms up to different pages :)

Comment: So you are suggesting to use an edit page instead of having the read and update operation in the same page? 
Another thing that i don't understand, why in the label data shows, instead in text input not? Tecnically, they have the same behavior, or am i wrong?

Comment: Yes. Make a separate edit page, for each car. Laravel resource controllers have built-in support for this. Regarding the data displaying in the labels: the second argument of `Form::label` should be the name of the field (like you did with Phone). When using `Form::model` you shouldn't use the value argument for your inputs. That gets filled automagically :)